# How to solve generic predicate in where clause item?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, func

i face to face 3 errors on where clause"**_list.Where<T>(whereClause)** " how to solve it?

**Error 1**
 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FuncMetodunuTaniyalim3.DataModel.Customer>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' has some invalid arguments
**Error 2** Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FuncMetodunuTaniyalim3.DataModel.Customer>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<T>'
**Error 3** Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Func<T,bool>' to 'System.Func<T,int,bool>'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FuncMetodunuTaniyalim3
{
    public class Search<T> where T : class
    {
         private  List<DataModel.Customer> _list;

         public Search()
         {
             _list = new List<DataModel.Customer>();
         }
        public int Find(Func<T, bool> whereClause)
        {
            return _list.IndexOf(_list.Where<T>(whereClause).FirstOrDefault<T>());
        }
    }

    //Repository
    public class DataModel
    {
        private IEnumerable<Customer> customers;

        public List<Customer> Customers
        {
            get { return customers.ToList(); }

        }


        public DataModel()
        {
            customers = new[] { new Customer(){ Id=1, Name="cbfghg", SurName="hfh", Age=29, Dept=0, Income=100},
                                new Customer(){ Id=2, Name="hfghfhf", SurName="erhfghfhfhem", Age=0,Dept=45, Income=300},
                                new Customer(){ Id=3, Name="hgfhgfhf", SurName="balhfghgfhfgh", Age=33, Dept=20, Income=150}};
        }

        //Model
        public class Customer
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string SurName { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public int Income { get; set; }
            public int Dept { get; set; }

            public Customer()
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Search class contains a `List<Customer>`. Probably you meant to use `List<T>`:

```
public class Search<T> where T : class
{
    private List<T> _list;

    public Search()
    {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }
    public int Find(Func<T, bool> whereClause)
    {
        return _list.IndexOf(_list.Where<T>(whereClause).FirstOrDefault<T>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your list is a `List<DataModel.Customer>`, while your predicate is a `Func<T, bool>`. Change the type of your predicate to `Func<DataModel.Customer, bool>` or change your list type to `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, because `List<DataModel.Customer>` implements `IEnumerable<DataModel.Customer>`
Look at method documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx Maybe you want _list as `List<T>` there?